# Remove 'contents' from every single page number heading

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, verse

Whenever I use 'table of contents', the word 'contents' appears above EVERY SIGNLE PAGE I format, right next to the page number. How do I get rid of this?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[e book,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final,show trims]{memoir}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, includefoot,includehead,top=0.4in, left=.4in, right=0.4in, bottom=0.4in, bindingoffset=.75in]{geometry}

\title{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont{\HUGE{\bfseries{Selected Poems:}}}}
\author{\Large A Chrestomathy}
\date{}
\usepackage{verse}


\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}
\maketitle
\end{titlingpage}
\newpage
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\poemtitle{Introduction}
\newpage
\poemtitle{Introduction2}
\end{document}
```

If you run this, you will see every page (Introduction, Introduction2) has the word 'contents' above the page number. It's irritating that nobody seems to have the same issue anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the desired result, you can use either

`\pagestyle{plain}`

or redefine `\poemtitlemark` (provided by package `verse`) to set the marks to the poemtitle

`\renewcommand\poemtitlemark[1]{\markboth{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}`

or to clear the marks

`\renewcommand\poemtitlemark[1]{\markboth{}{}}`